# about check_sum in ping

Tags: c, pointers, network-programming

i have read the code of ping. and i'm confused this code

```
    *(u_char *)(&u) = *(u_char *)w ;
```

in this function,i think u have a value of 0, why assignment again.

```
/*
 *                      I N _ C K S U M
 *
 * Checksum routine for Internet Protocol family headers (C Version)
 *
 */
in_cksum(addr, len)
u_short *addr;
int len;
{
        register int nleft = len;
        register u_short *w = addr;
        register u_short answer;
        register int sum = 0;

        /*
         *  Our algorithm is simple, using a 32 bit accumulator (sum),
         *  we add sequential 16 bit words to it, and at the end, fold
         *  back all the carry bits from the top 16 bits into the lower
         *  16 bits.
         */
        while( nleft > 1 )  {
                sum += *w++;
                nleft -= 2;
        }

        /* mop up an odd byte, if necessary */
        if( nleft == 1 ) {
                u_short u = 0;

                *(u_char *)(&u) = *(u_char *)w ;
                sum += u;
        }

        /*
         * add back carry outs from top 16 bits to low 16 bits
         */
        sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);     /* add hi 16 to low 16 */
        sum += (sum >> 16);                     /* add carry */
        answer = ~sum;                          /* truncate to 16 bits */
        return (answer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
&u
```

is a pointer to `u`.

```
(u_char *)(&u)
```

is a `u_char` pointer to `u`.

```
*(u_char *)(&u)
```

dereferences that pointer, so

```
*(u_char *)(&u) = *(u_char *)w ;
```

copies the first byte from `w` into the first byte of `u`. The second byte is zero.

(Assuming, as the authors of this code have done, that `short` is 16 bits wide. According to the C standard, that's not necessarily true.)

Comment: so why not write it like that: `sum += (*w) & 0xff;`?

Comment: @duedl0r: I didn't write this code and I can't comment on it in detail, but note that the way it's written, it produces different result depending on endianness. `(*w) & 0xff` is not equal to `*(u_char *)w` on all platforms.